# Plugins in Gazebo 9 - ROS Melodic

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am having trouble using plugins in Gazebo 9.0.0, that came pre-installed with ROS. The specific plugin I'm trying to make work is the Actor Collions plugin (Found [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-requests/2875/example-plugin-that-enables-collisions))

I have tried downloading the plugin files, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the collision of the actor at all.

Is this due to Gazebo not being a source installation, or something else entirely?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
I followed the install tutorial [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install#Alternativeinstallation:step-by-step), to install Gazebo 9.13.  
 I then downloaded the example files from the OSRF [bitckbucket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/downloads/?tab=tags) using the 9.13 tag. I put the actor_collisions example folder in a workspace by itself and tried running "gazebo actor_collisions.world" from the terminal. 
I have tried both with and without using catkin_make to build my workspace first. The result is the actor walking around among the objects, but there's still no collision.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24778/plugins-in-gazebo-9---ros-melodic/) by [Anton](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25369/anton/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-04-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, have you tried running it with the  `--verbose` flag?

When I follow the steps you linked and run: `gazebo ../actor_collisions.world --verbose` I get the error that the plugin could not be found:

`Failed to load plugin libActorCollisionsPlugin.so: libActorCollisionsPlugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

If this is your case, you might need to set the environment variable, to tell Gazebo where to look for your plugin, something like this: `export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH:{path_to_your_ws}/actor_collisions/build` and run the command again.

---

Originally posted by [relffok](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25674/relffok/) with karma: 26 on 2020-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25369/anton/) on 2020-04-28**:
Thank you! This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As you can see on the [changelog](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/gazebo9/Changelog.md), for Gazebo major version 9, that plugin is only available from Gazebo 9.1.0. Follow the install instructions [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install#Alternativeinstallation:step-by-step) to install the latest minor release.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25369/anton/) on 2020-04-09**:
Thanks, that makes sense! As I'm using ROS Melodic, I would prefer to not use anything newer than Gazebo 9.x. What is the easiest way to install 9.13? When I use the command "sudo apt-get install gazebo9=9.13.0", i get an error that says this version was not found

EDIT:
"sudo apt-get install gazebo9=9.13.0-1*" worked. Will test if this solves my initial problem

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25369/anton/) on 2020-04-09**:
Upgrading to 9.13 did not fix the issue. I downloaded the example files from the 9.13 commit on Bitbucket (https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/commits/05ed9a675a0e) so I think the files are correct...

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-04-09**:
Oh no :/ Could you update the question with steps to reproduce the issue and the error output you're seeing?

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25369/anton/) on 2020-04-10**:
Yeah :/ I have updated the question, looking forward to your response :)

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25369/anton/) on 2020-04-21**:
Hello chapulina, do you by chance have an update?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-04-21**:
Did you follow these instructions? Also, does running with `--verbose` print any errors? https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/blob/gazebo9/examples/plugins/actor_collisions/README.md

**Comment by [Anton](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25369/anton/) on 2020-04-28**:
Thank you, your link along with relffok's answer solved my issue :)